# How to validate if at least 1 of the radio button is selected out of 7 Using Selenium

Tags: automated-testing

```
<label for="experience">Years of Experience:</label>
<input name="experience" type="radio" value="one" style="">
<input name="experience" type="radio" value="two">
<input name="experience" type="radio" value="three">
<input name="experience" type="radio" value="four">
......
.....
<input name="experience" type="radio" value="above seven">
```

This does not give me a proper result.

```
WebElement val = driver.findElement(By.name("experience"));
List<WebElement>radios = val.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type ='radio']"));
radios.get(0).getAttribute("checked")
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your code:

```
// The line below will find the first input. This line is useless
WebElement val = driver.findElement(By.name("experience"));
// Since val only contains the first input, radios will be an empty list
List<WebElement> radios = val.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type ='radio']"));
// Below will raise an expection, because the list is empty
radios.get(0).getAttribute("checked")
```

A suggestion:

```
// Finding all radios
List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[name='experience']"));
// Let's filter out only the checked radios. 
// In Selenium, isSelected will verify if it is checked
List<WebElement> checkedRadios = radios.stream().filter(radio -> radio.isSelected() ).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Let's check if we have found at least one checked radio button
Boolean hasCheckedRadio = !checkedRadios.isEmpty();
```

The code above necessarily walks through all radios. If you are worried about performance, you can wrap the code in a method and run a for loop which stops as soons as it finds a checked radio:

```
List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[name='experience']"));
for (WebElement radio : radios) {
    if(radio.isSelected()) return true;
}
return false;
```